# I want to hide and un hide the table row in .aspx form on the text change event of DropDownlist without Refreshing the whole web page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

i use ajax but i can't works properly. and also javaScript not works i do that kindly help me and tel me whats the problem.

1. want to hide table row if the selected value is yes
2. must not refresh the whole page

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //Attaching the change event of dropdown list
            $('#<%= _ddlUserType.ClientID %>').change(function () {
                var select = $("#<%=_ddlUserType.ClientID %> > option:selected").val();
                if (select == "Yes") {
                    tblcompany.show();

                }
                else {
                    tblcompany.hide();
                }
            });
        });
```

```html
     <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow6" runat="server">
                            <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell12" runat="server">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="User Type"></asp:Label>

                            </asp:TableCell>

                            <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell13" runat="server">
                                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server"> 
                                    <ContentTemplate> 
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="_ddlUserType" runat="server" class="input username" Width="245px" ClientIDMode="Static" AutoPostBack="true" >
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Select User Type" Value="No"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Admin" Value="Yes"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Agent" Value="Yes"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Normal User" Value="No"></asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                 </ContentTemplate>
                        <Triggers>
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="_ddlUserType" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                        </Triggers>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                            </asp:TableCell>
                        </asp:TableRow>

                        <asp:TableRow ID="_tblRowCompany" runat="server">

                            <asp:TableCell runat="server" ColumnSpan="2">


                                <asp:Table ID="tblcompany" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
                                    <asp:TableRow runat="server">
                                        <asp:TableHeaderCell runat="server" ColumnSpan="2">
                                <div class="header">
                                <span>Fill out the form below to Register your Company.</span>
                                    </div>
                                        </asp:TableHeaderCell>
                                    </asp:TableRow>
                                    <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow8" runat="server">

                                        <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell16" runat="server">

                                            <asp:Label ID="_lblCompanyName" runat="server" Text="Companny Name"></asp:Label>
                                        </asp:TableCell>
                                        <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell17" runat="server">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="_txtRegisterCompanyName" runat="server" class="input username"  value="Company Name" onfocus="this.value=''" OnTextChanged="_txtRegisterCompanyName_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </asp:TableCell>
                                    </asp:TableRow>
                                    <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow9" runat="server">
                                        <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell18" runat="server">
                                            <asp:Label ID="_lblEmail" runat="server" Text="Companny Email"></asp:Label>
                                        </asp:TableCell>
                                        <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell19" runat="server">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="_txtRegisterCompanyEmail" runat="server" class="input username" value="Company Email" onfocus="this.value=''"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </asp:TableCell>
                                    </asp:TableRow>
                                    <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow10" runat="server">
                                        <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell20" runat="server">
                                            <asp:Label ID="Lab" runat="server" Text="Companny Contact"></asp:Label>
                                        </asp:TableCell>
                                        <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell21" runat="server">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="_txtRegisterCompanyContact" runat="server" class="input username" value="Company Contact" onfocus="this.value=''"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </asp:TableCell>
                                    </asp:TableRow>
                                    <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow11" runat="server">
                                        <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell22" runat="server">
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Companny Address"></asp:Label>
                                        </asp:TableCell>
                                        <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell23" runat="server">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="_txtRegisterCompanyAddress" runat="server" class="input username" value="Company Address" onfocus="this.value=''"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </asp:TableCell>
                                    </asp:TableRow>
                                    <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow12" runat="server">
                                        <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell24" runat="server">
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Companny Website"></asp:Label>
                                        </asp:TableCell>
                                        <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell25" runat="server">
 <asp:scriptmanager ID="Scriptmanager1" runat="server"></asp:scriptmanager>  **strong text**                                     
       <asp:TextBox ID="_txtRegisterCompanyWebsite" runat="server" class="input username" value="Company Website" onfocus="this.value=''"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </asp:TableCell>
                                    </asp:TableRow>
                                </asp:Table>
                            </asp:TableCell>
                        </asp:TableRow>
```

Comment: It looks like you're confusing your server-side and client-side code. $('#<%= _ddlUserType.ClientID %>') is incorrect. _ddlUserType.ClientID is somethign that only makes sense server-side; ClientID is a property of the asp server control _ddlUserType. This would get rendered in your browser as a select with id="_ddlUserType"

What you probably want is $('#_ddlUserType') to get your select tag.

Comment: Note: if you're using a master page, you might have to prepend something like 'main_' or somethign similar before that id. A good way to know is to just right click on it in the browser, go to "Inspect Element", and looking at the id that shows up here.

Comment: You've used ClientID on your drop down list, but you're using a javascript variable for tblcompany (A server-side table) without using a jQuery selector or your ClientID to get the full ID.

Comment: i try these two method also Jquery and update pannal